# Assign worksheet range using a string variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string variable with the following value assigned:

`Answer = ""M3:AM3""`

I want to assign this variable to a Range as follows:

```
DIM xlRange As Excel.Range
Set xlRange = xlApp.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Answer)
```

This generates the error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I also tried the following to paste values using the variable for the range and got the same error:

```
xlApp.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Answer).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Can someone please help me resolve this?
Thanks.

Comment: `""M3:AM3""` - what's with the doubled-up quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is the xlApp, which is not defined:

```
DIM xlApp as Excel.Application
```

If you have already have it defined, then the problem is the double quote, which does not mean anything to VBA. Also you have another problem which is the hierarchy:

```
 xlApp.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Answer)
```

after xlApp you have to define a WORKBOOK and not a WORKSHEET. So you need to give the workbook of Sheet1 too

so Assuming:

```
Answer="M3:AM3"
```

you can write:

```
 Set xlApp = Application
 Set xlRange = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Answer)
```

If you know the name of the workbook for certain, then you can replace ActiveWorkbook with Workbooks("MyWorkbookName").